# Dual graph of an arbitrary (planar) graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Every planar graph has a [dual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph). How can I obtain it with *Mathematica*?

I know that `GraphData` provides the `DualGraph` property for its named graphs, but I have found no method for computing the dual of an arbitrary (non-named) graph. Even *Combinatorica* seems to lack it.

Answer (score 18):

**Update:** obviously incorrect statements are removed.

I think WM doesn't include DualGraph-function because it is usually multigraph and non unique.

As far as I have read in Wikipedia a dual graph $G^*$ depends on planar embedding of $G$.  If you ask for a *some* dual graph for a given graph, then here is my brute force heuristic algorithm. It is based on algorithm (given below) which yields the faces (and I do not guarantee that it is correct):

The pseudo-code is as follows:

1. `pseudofaces={}`
2. `graph0` = spanning tree of `graph`
3. `edges0` = all edges of `graph` which are not in `graph0`
4. While `edges0` is non empty

   1. find `edge` from `edges0` such that its vertices have shortest `path` in `graph0`
   2. Append `path` to `pseudofaces`
   3. Remove `edge` from `edges0`
   4. Add `edge` to `graph0`
5. return `pseudofaces`

Here is *Mathematica* implementation.

```
(* simple Kruskal's algorithm without sorting *)
SpanningTree[graph_] := Module[{label, edges = EdgeList[graph]}, 
Pick[edges, Table[If[UnsameQ[#1, #2], #2 = #1; True, False] & @@ Sort[label /@ edge], {edge, edges}]]]
```

It yields a spanning tree:

```
graph = GridGraph[{5, 9}];
HighlightGraph[graph, SpanningTree[graph]]
```

[image]

```
makeEges[list_] := Sort /@ UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[list, 2, 1]

(* FindFace : finds the smallest cycle. This cycle is a pseudo-face. *)
FindFace[graph_, edges_] := MapAt[makeEges, 
    First@SortBy[Transpose[{FindShortestPath[graph, Sequence @@ #] & /@ edges, edges}],
    Composition[Length, First]], 1]

(* Append analyzed edge to a graph *)
appendEge[graph_, edge_] := Graph@Append[EdgeList[graph], edge]

iteration[graph_, {}] := $faces;

iteration[graph_, edges_] := iteration[AppendTo[$faces, Flatten[#]]; appendEge[graph, Last@#], 
     DeleteCases[edges, Last@#]] &[FindFace[graph, edges]]

(* Faces : returns all pseudo-faces of a graph *)
Faces[graph_] := Block[{$faces = {}, tree = SpanningTree[graph]},
    iteration[Graph[tree], Complement[EdgeList[graph], tree]]]
```

It works as follows:

```
faces = Faces[graph];
Manipulate[HighlightGraph[graph, faces[[n]]], {n, 1, Length@faces, 1}]
```

[image]

The last step is to construct the dual graph from the faces:

```
 shareQ[set1_, set2_] := Length@Intersection[set1, set2] > 0;

 (* connecting all faces *)
 innerDualEdges[faces_] := Join @@ Table[
      Table[If[shareQ @@ faces[[{i, j}]], UndirectedEdge[i, j], Unevaluated@Sequence[]],
      {j, i + 1, Length[faces]}], {i, 1, Length[faces] - 1}]

 (* next two functions find the faces on the boundary *)
 boundaryEdges[faces_] := 
      Module[{edges = Join @@ faces}, Select[Union[edges], (Count[edges, #] == 1) &]]
 boundaryFaces[faces_, outerEdges_] := 
      Select[Range@Length@faces, shareQ[faces[[#]], outerEdges] &];

 (* altogether *)
 DualGraph[faces_] := Graph[DeleteDuplicates@Join[innerDualEdges[faces],
      Thread@UndirectedEdge[0, boundaryFaces[faces, boundaryEdges[faces]]]]]
```

That's all.

```
 DualGraph[faces]
```

[image]

If you do not consider the outer space as a face, then you can ask:

```
 Graph[innerDualEdges[faces]]
```

[image]

You can also compare it with *Mathematica* internals:

```
 IsomorphicGraphQ[GraphData["IcosahedralGraph", "DualGraph"], 
 DualGraph[Faces[GraphData["IcosahedralGraph"]]]]
 (* True *)
```

Full notebook is available [here](http://goo.gl/wCjTxN).

Comment: +1 ... by the by in M10 there will be multigraph, here's some evidence http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MultigraphQ.html

Comment: Grisha Kirilin's method doesn't seem to work for some (even very small) examples.

Eg. `IsomorphicGraphQ` outputs `False` both times here:


    `name = "SelfDualGraph1";
    IsomorphicGraphQ[GraphData[name,"DualGraph"],DualGraph[Faces[GraphData[name]]]]`


   `name = {"JohnsonSkeleton", 26};
    IsomorphicGraphQ[GraphData[name, "DualGraph"],DualGraph[Faces[GraphData[name]]]]`


Can this method be fixed or is there a more reliable way to get a dual graph? In particular I want to find the dual graphs of the `JohnsonSkeleton`s which `GraphData` doesn't have complete information for.

Answer (score 7):

[`DualPlanarGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DualPlanarGraph.html) is a new function in Mathematica 13.0. It works with directed graphs and multigraphs.

Answer (score 5):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now includes functionality to find the faces of a planar graph, or to find the dual graph.

Demo:

```
g = IGTriangularLattice[3, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
IGFaces[g]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 6, 5, 4, 2}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 5, 3}, {3, 5, 6}} *)

IGDualGraph[g]
```

[image]

The vertices of the dual are in the same order as the result of `IGFaces`.