# How to obtain the cell-adjacency graph of a mesh?

Tags: performance-tuning, graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry, mesh

In addition to the accepted answer, [see also the answer by Chip Hurst.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166491/12) This functionality is built in, but not documented.

---

Given an arbitrary mesh region, how can I efficiently obtain the graph describing the adjacency structure of mesh cells?

For example, given the following mesh,

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"}]
```

[image]

I need this `Graph`:

[image]

It tells me that e.g. cells 4 and 5 are neighbours.

This example was for 2D cells, but the problem can be stated generally for cells of any dimension:

- two edges (1D cells) are adjacent if they have a common point
- two faces (2D cells) are adjacent if they have a common edge
- two 3D cells are adjacent if they have a common face
- ...

I am looking both for specialized methods to obtain the face-adjacency graph of a 2D or 3D mesh, and general methods to obtain the $k$-dimensional cell adjacency graph of a $d > k$ dimensional mesh.

---

Here's a naïve method for face-adjacency. It is too slow for practical use due to its $O(n^2)$ complexity.

```
SimpleGraph[
 RelationGraph[
  Length@Intersection[First@MeshCells[mesh, #1], First@MeshCells[mesh, #2]] >= 2 &,
  MeshCellIndex[mesh, 2]
  ],
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
 ]
```

This method exploits the fact that if two polygons (faces) are adjacent, then they will have (at least) two points in common.  For example, `Polygon[{14, 8, 7, 11}]` and `Polygon[{11, 7, 2, 4, 13}]` have points `7` and `11` in common. It generalizes to higher dimensions as well: two 3D cells are adjacent if they have at least 3 points in common.

However, it is quite slow because `RelationGraph` will test each pair of cells for adjacency.

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {500, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];

RelationGraph[
   Length@Intersection[First@MeshCells[mesh, #1], 
       First@MeshCells[mesh, #2]] >= 2 &,
   MeshCellIndex[mesh, 2]
   ]; // AbsoluteTiming

(* {2.36978, Null} *)
```

While this method can be sped up by a constant factor with minor tweaks, this won't fix the core problem: quadratic complexity.

```
cells = MeshCells[mesh, 2][[All, 1]];        
RelationGraph[Length@Intersection[#1, #2] >= 2 &, cells]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.815857, Null} *)
```

1 second for only 500 cells is still too slow.  Can we do significantly better?

Comment: You really need only the connectivity graph, not the vertex positions? I think I can do something about it...

Comment: If you have the initial points, wouldn't it be easier to use `DelaunayMesh` and `MeshPrimitives`? As in `pi = PositionIndex[MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[pts], 0][[;; , 1]]][[;; , 1]]`, `Graph[Values[pi], MeshPrimitives[DelaunayMesh[pts], 1][[;; , 1]] /. pi, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I only need the connectivity graph.  Vertex positions are irrelevant.

Comment: @aardvark2012 The VoronoiMesh was just an example. I am looking for a method that works for any mesh. I used a Voronoi mesh as an example because, unlike most other meshes one might encounter in Mathematica, its cells are not triangles (some methods may work only for triangles).

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/90109/calculate-dual-graph-of-planar-graphics-map https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52056/dual-graph-of-an-arbitrary-planar-graph

Comment: I did not read the details of this question but for future readers note that `MeshConnectivityGraph` was later introduced in version 12.1 (2020).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think, I found a general and even faster way, but I haven't tested it for $1$- or $3$-dimensional `MeshRegions`.

The following function computes the cell-vertex-adjacency matrix `A`. Two $d$-dimensional cells ($d>0$) are adjacent if they share at least $d$ common points. We can find these pairs by looking for entries $\geq d$ in `A.Transpose[A]`.

```
ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray;
ClearAll[getCellCellAdjacencyList];
getCellCellAdjacencyList[R_MeshRegion, d_] := 
 Module[{pts, cells, A, lens, n, m, nn},
  pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
  cells = ToPack[MeshCells[R, d][[All, 1]]];
  lens = Length /@ cells;
  n = Length[pts];
  m = Length[cells];
  nn = Total[lens];
  A = SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m, n}, 0, {1, {
       ToPack[Join[{0}, Accumulate[lens]]],
       ArrayReshape[Flatten[Sort /@ cells], {nn, 1}]
       },
      ConstantArray[1, nn]}};
  SparseArray[
    UnitStep[UpperTriangularize[A.Transpose[A], 1] -  d]
  ]["NonzeroPositions"]
  ]
```

A special treatment is necessary for 0-dimensional cells; it's just the edges that we need.

```
getCellCellAdjacencyList[R_MeshRegion, 0] := ToPack[MeshCells[R, 1][[All, 1]]]
```

Here are some examples:

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
R = VoronoiMesh[pts];

GraphicsGrid[Table[
  {VoronoiMesh[pts, MeshCellLabel -> {d -> "Index"}],
   Graph[getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, d], VertexLabels -> "Name"]
   }, {d, 0, 2}], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

And some timings for comparison:

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
R = VoronoiMesh[pts]; // RepeatedTiming
getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 0]; // RepeatedTiming
getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 1]; // RepeatedTiming
getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 2]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.636, Null}
>
> {0.015, Null}
>
> {0.031, Null}
>
> {0.041, Null}

**Edit**

It's now rather straight-forward to write methods for the various adjacency matrices, lists, and graphs, even for cells of different dimensions (see below).

**Edit 2**

As [Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/4346) pointed out, the adjacency matrix of a `MeshRegion` `R` for distinct dimensions `d1`, `d2` can be found as pattern `SparseArray`  under `R["ConnectivityMatrix"[d1,d2]]`. (Its "RowPointers" and "ColumnIndices" must have been computed immediately when the `MeshRegion` was built.)

Many applications of adjacency matrices, in particular in finite elements, need `1` instead of `Pattern` as nonzero entries. Even computing vertex rings in a graph by using `MatrixPower`s of the adjacency matrix is considerably faster with (real) numeric matrices. <s>A remedy could be the function `SparseArrayFromPatternArray` below.</s> As Chip Hurst has pointed out, we can turn a pattern array into a numerical one with `Unitize`. I updated my old code to utilize this observation, leading to a tremendous performance boost. Somewhat surprisingly, even the old implementation of `CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 1, 2]` tends to be faster than `R["ConnectivityMatrix"[1,2]]`, so that I decided to use the new approach only for the case when either `d1` or `d2` is equal to `0`.

```
CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, d_, 0] := If[MeshCellCount[R, d] > 0,
   Unitize[R["ConnectivityMatrix"[d, 0]]],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, 0, d_] := If[MeshCellCount[R, d] > 0,
   Unitize[R["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, d]]],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, 0, 0] := 
  If[MeshCellCount[R, 1] > 0,
   With[{A = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 0, 1]},
    With[{B = A.Transpose[A]},
     SparseArray[B - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[B]]]
     ]
    ],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyMatrix[R_MeshRegion, d1_, d2_] := 
  If[(MeshCellCount[R, d1] > 0) && (MeshCellCount[R, d2] > 0), 
   With[{B = CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, d1, 0].CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 0, d2]},
    SparseArray[
     If[d1 == d2,
      UnitStep[B - DiagonalMatrix[Diagonal[B]] - d1],
      UnitStep[B - (Min[d1, d2] + 1)]
      ]
     ]
    ],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyLists[R_MeshRegion, d1_, d2_] := 
  If[(MeshCellCount[R, d1] > 0) && (MeshCellCount[R, d2] > 0),
   Module[{i1, i2, data},
    data = If[d1 == d2,
      UpperTriangularize[CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, d1, d2], 1]["NonzeroPositions"], 
      CellAdjacencyMatrix[R, d1, d2]["NonzeroPositions"]
      ];
    If[Length[data] > 0,
     {i1, i2} = Transpose[data];
     Transpose[
      {
       Transpose[{ConstantArray[d1, {Length[i1]}], i1}],
       Transpose[{ConstantArray[d2, {Length[i2]}], i2}]
       }
      ],
     {}
     ]
    ],
   {}
   ];

CellAdjacencyGraph[R_MeshRegion, d1_, d2_] := Graph[
   Join[MeshCellIndex[R, d1], MeshCellIndex[R, d2]],
   UndirectedEdge @@@ CellAdjacencyLists[R, d1, d2],
   VertexLabels -> "Name"
   ];
```

Note that `CellAdjacencyLists` and `CellAdjacencyGraph` use labels that are compatible with those obtained from `MeshCellIndex`.
Applied to Szabolcs's example `MeshRegion`, theses graphs look as follows:

```
GraphicsGrid[
 Table[CellAdjacencyGraph[R, d1, d2], {d1, 0, 2}, {d2, 0, 2}], 
 ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

As for comparing the performance of these new implementations to `getCellCellAdjacencyList`:

```
{
 getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
 getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
 getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
 }
{
 CellAdjacencyLists[R, 0, 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
 CellAdjacencyLists[R, 1, 1]; // RepeatedTiming // First,
 CellAdjacencyLists[R, 2, 2]; // RepeatedTiming // First
 }
```

> {0.015, 0.030, 0.037}
>
> {0.0068, 0.011, 0.0066}

Comment: Thank you for this! I haven't forgotten, and I will accept an answer in due time.

Comment: Would you mind if I incorporated some of this into IGraph/M (with credits of course)?  https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/

Comment: @Szabolcs No, I would not. To the contrary: I would feel honored! I would also be thankful for any improvements you might find as I use these things for my own work on surface meshes.

Comment: Just a note that while `Transpose[Transpose[edges][[{2, 1}]]` is faster than `Reverse[edges, {2}]`, it fails on `{}`.  I think that given that computing the edge list in that function takes two orders of magnitude longer for big meshes, the slowdown due to `Reverse` is acceptable.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you! Good point. I will add a check against empty edge lists. You are right that `MeshCells[R, 1]` takes pretty long. In an ideal word, the edge list would be cached within the `MeshRegion` for it is used for quite a number of things. Actually, that's what I do in my own data type for simplicial surfaces. If you subtract the time for getting the `edges`, then `Reverse` slows down building the sparse matrix by a factor of two. This is why I prefer a check against emptiness of the edge list. As long as `MeshRegions` don't cache the edge list, this is a matter of taste, though.

Comment: [Putting your functions to good use :-)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/145313/12)

Comment: @Szabolcs Nice to see! Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 12):

I need three compiled helper functions:

```
getEdgesFromPolygons = Compile[{{f, _Integer, 1}},
   Table[
    {
     Min[Compile`GetElement[f, i], Compile`GetElement[f, Mod[i + 1, Length[f], 1]]], 
     Max[Compile`GetElement[f, i], Compile`GetElement[f, Mod[i + 1, Length[f], 1]]]
     },
    {i, 1, Length[f]}
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
takeSortedThread = Compile[{{data, _Integer, 1}, {ran, _Integer, 1}},
   Sort[Part[data, ran[[1]] ;; ran[[2]]]],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
extractIntegerFromSparseMatrix = Compile[
   {{vals, _Integer, 1}, {rp, _Integer, 1}, {ci, _Integer, 
     1}, {background, _Integer},
    {i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
   Block[{k},
    k = rp[[i]] + 1;
    While[k < rp[[i + 1]] + 1 && ci[[k]] != j, ++k];
    If[k == rp[[i + 1]] + 1, background, vals[[k]]]
    ],
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

The following functions takes a `MeshRegion` and finds all pairs of neighboring two-dimensional `MeshCells`. First, it generates a list of all edges (with sorted indices) and creates a lookup table for edges in form of a `SparseArray`. With the lookup table, we can find the indices of all edges bounding a given polygon, so that we can build the `SparseArray` `edgepolygonadjacencymatrix`, whose `"AdjacencyLists"` is what we are looking for. The method should have linear complexity.

```
ToPack = Developer`ToPackedArray;
getPolygonPolygonAdjacencyList[R_MeshRegion] := 
 Module[{pts, polygons, edgesfrompolygons, edges, edgelookupcontainer,
    polyranges, polygonsneighedges, edgepolygonadjacencymatrix, acc},
  pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
  polygons = ToPack[MeshCells[R, 2][[All, 1]]];
  edgesfrompolygons =  ToPack[Flatten[getEdgesFromPolygons[polygons], 1]];
  edges = DeleteDuplicates[edgesfrompolygons];
  edgelookupcontainer = 
   SparseArray[
    Rule[Join[edges, Transpose[Transpose[edges][[{2, 1}]]]], 
     Join[Range[1, Length[edges]], Range[1, Length[edges]]]], {Length[
      pts], Length[pts]}];
  acc = Join[{0}, Accumulate[ToPack[Length /@ polygons]]];
  polyranges = Transpose[{Most[acc] + 1, Rest[acc]}];
  polygonsneighedges = takeSortedThread[extractIntegerFromSparseMatrix[
      edgelookupcontainer["NonzeroValues"],
      edgelookupcontainer["RowPointers"],
      Flatten@edgelookupcontainer["ColumnIndices"],
      edgelookupcontainer["Background"],
      edgesfrompolygons[[All, 1]],
      edgesfrompolygons[[All, 2]]],
     polyranges];
  edgepolygonadjacencymatrix = Transpose@With[{
      n = Length[edges], m = Length[polygons],
      data = ToPack[Flatten[polygonsneighedges]]
      },
     SparseArray @@ {Automatic, {m, n}, 
       0, {1, {acc, Transpose[{data}]}, ConstantArray[1, Length[data]]}}
     ];
  Select[(edgepolygonadjacencymatrix["AdjacencyLists"]), Length[#] == 2 &]
  ]
```

Testing with OP's example:

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
R = VoronoiMesh[pts, MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"}]
Graph[
 UndirectedEdge @@@ getPolygonPolygonAdjacencyList[R],
 VertexLabels -> "Name"
 ]
```

[image]

[image]

Speed test

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
R = VoronoiMesh[pts, 
    MeshCellLabel -> {2 -> "Index"}]; // RepeatedTiming
getPolygonPolygonAdjacencyList[R]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.625, Null}
>
> {0.086, Null}

**Edit**

Slight improvement by merging `Sort` into `takeThread` (`takeThread` replaced by `takeSortedThread`).

Slight improvement by replacing `Extract` with `extractIntegerFromSparseMatrix`.

Answer (score 11):

Here's another way.

Data from OP:

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts];
```

Get the adjacency matrix:

```
conn = mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]];
adj = conn.Transpose[conn];
```

Find the cell centroids for visualization purposes:

```
centers = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];

g = AdjacencyGraph[adj, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", VertexCoordinates -> centers];

Show[mesh, g]
```

[image]

Using the same profiling code as Henrik, we have

```
SeedRandom[123]
pts = RandomReal[1, {10000, 2}];
R = VoronoiMesh[pts]; // RepeatedTiming

getCellCellAdjacencyList[R, 2]; // RepeatedTiming

RepeatedTiming[
  conn = R["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]];
  conn . Transpose[conn];
]
```

> {0.632, Null}
>
> {0.042, Null}
>
> {0.012, Null}

Comment: So this was already built in ... it's really a pity that all this stuff is undocumented!!

Comment: I imagine it's partly because this is not a good design for documented functionality. `"ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]` is quite strange looking.

Comment: Just write it as `mesh@"ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]` and it looks fine. It's exactly the same notation that J/Link uses for method calls.  The `@` replaces the `.` that most object-oriented languages would use.

Comment: Of course I did try `mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"]`, but I stopped experimenting after it spit out `Removed[$$Failed]`. I didn't realize that it needed extra arguments.

Comment: Oh my, that's so embarassing. Why aren't these things documented? @Szabolcs Of course I don't mind if you make this the accepted answer.

Comment: @ChipHurst Do you know of an efficient way to turn `R["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]]` into a numerical array with `1` instead of `Pattern` as nonzero values? That would be very useful for many applications...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher this works: `SparseArray[ArrayRules[mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]]/.{({x_, y_} -> _ ) -> {x, y} -> 1}]` Gross, but effective.

Comment: @IgorRivin, thanks for the hint. Note that this produces a matrix with ones everywhere. Moreover, `Replace` is rather slow; `B = Module[{rules},
  rules = ArrayRules[mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]]];
  rules[[1 ;; -2, 2]] = 1;
  SparseArray[rules]
  ]` is almost twice as fast. When working with large `SparseArrays`, I try to avoid `ArrayRules` at all cost because it unpacks `Arrays` so that `SparseArray@*ArrayRules` is a rather costly identity mapping. Notice also the function `SparseArrayFromPatternArray` from my post; it is about ten times faster than the approach with `Replace`.

Comment: @HnerikScuhmacher The $10 question is: what is the point of outputting the pattern array, given how much pain there is in converting into anything useful...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It looks like `Unitize[R["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]]]` replaces `Pattern` with `1`!

Comment: @ChipHurst Hah! Brilliant! The idea to apply `Unitize` to anything nonnumerical would never have come to my mind.

Comment: Is there a similarly robust way to get the vertex-vertex adjacency matrix?  `mesh["AdjacencyMatrix"]` does not always work.

Comment: Other than creating a temporary incidence matrix, no I don't. `conn = mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[0, 2]]; adj = conn . Transpose[conn];`

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this approach when considering square meshes. Neighbouring cells get somehow mixed up. Could you please take a look at the follow up question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212944/cell-adjacency-graph-of-a-square-mesh

Answer (score 10):

Using a few *undocumented* properties of `MeshRegion[]` objects, we have the following:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123];
            vm = VoronoiMesh[RandomReal[1, {10, 2}]]];

Show[vm,
     Graph[Range[vm["FaceCount"]], 
           Union[Sort /@ Flatten[MapIndexed[Thread[UndirectedEdge[#2[[1]], #1]] &, 
                                            vm["FaceFaceConnectivity"]]]],
           PlotTheme -> "ClassicDiagram", 
           VertexCoordinates -> Map[Mean, vm["FaceCoordinates"]]]]
```

[image: mesh and its face-face connectivity graph]

I'm not sure why the labels from this version are not consistent with the labels from `MeshCellLabel`, tho.

Comment: `vm["EdgeEdgeConnectivity"]` and `vm["VertexVertexConnectivity"]` might also be of interest.

Comment: Ah, "FaceFaceConnectivity" works for `MeshRegions` in the plane! I tried these properties several times for two-dimensional `MeshRegions` in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and it did not work. Seemingly, there is still a lot to be done internally...

Answer (score 3):

In version 12.1, the function `MeshConnectivityGraph[]` is now built-in. Using the examples in Henrik's answer:

```
Table[Show[MeshConnectivityGraph[mesh, k, VertexLabels -> "Index"]],
      {k, 0, 2}] // GraphicsRow
```

[image: mesh connectivities]

Answer (score 1):

Note `VoronoiMesh` is the dual of the `DelaunayMesh`, so

```
Show[mesh, 
 AdjacencyGraph[DelaunayMesh[pts]["AdjacencyMatrix"], 
  VertexCoordinates -> MeshCoordinates[DelaunayMesh[pts]], 
  EdgeStyle -> Red]]
```

[image: mesh and graph]

But I don't know how to get the right vertex label..