# How to create a neighboring list for a given triangulation and find the triangle and construct the tile?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

I am new to Mathematica and I am currently in need of some help with creating a neighboring list of triangles for a given triangulation and finding the path to the triangle containing the random point and constructing a tile. So basically, this problem involves the Delaunay Triangulation. I can generate the triangles using`DelaunayMesh` but I can't find the neighboring triangles, the path to the triangle containing the random point, and construct the tile. This is what I have so far.

```
(* Number of data points *)
numpts = 5;
(* Test data set *)
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {0.3, 0.4}};
dmesh = DelaunayMesh[pts];
(* Extract the triangle list from the Delaunay triangulation *)
tris = MeshCells[dmesh, 2];
numtris = Length[tris];
(* This demonstrates how to access the pts from the tris list *)
Print["Number of triangles numtris = ", numtris];
Do[
  Print["Tri ", i,
   " v1=", pts[[tris[[i, 1, 1]]]],
   " v2=", pts[[tris[[i, 1, 2]]]],
   " v3 = ", pts[[tris[[i, 1, 3]]]]],
  {i, 1, numtris}
  ];
(* Data structure to hold neighbor data *)
nghbrs = Table[{0, 0, 0}, {i, 1, numtris}];
```

I want to use do loops to find the neighboring list of triangles and the path but I don't know what to enter. Can anyone please help me by showing me what code (I would prefer simple coding as I am still new to this programming language) to enter in the do loops? I would definitely appreciate all the help I can get. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160457/38178). 
What you are looking for is `TNT = CellAdjacencyLists[dmesh, 2, 2]`. `TNT[[i]]` contains the list of all triangles neighboring triangle `i` (in the sense that they share an edge).

You can also create a graph `G = CellAdjacencyGraph[dmesh, 2, 2]` with the triangles' indices as vertices and with an edge between two vertices if and only if the respective triangles are neighbors. 
You can find the shortest path between the `i`th and `j`th triangle with
`FindShortestPath[G,i,j]`.

See also [Chip Hurst's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166491/38178) to the same post.

```
conn = dmesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]];
A = conn.Transpose[conn]
```

It gives you the triangle-triangle-adjacency matrix `A`; the neighbor lists can be obtained with `TNT = A["AdjacencyLists"]` and the graph with `G = AdjacencyGraph[A, VertexLabels -> "Name"]`.

Comment: Henrik Schumacher, I have tried to use Chip Hurst’s code but it doesn’t give me the neighbor lists in the structure that I have provided. Can you possibly show me how to get the neighbor lists to be in the structure that I provide?