# Adjacent faces in a discrete mesh

Tags: performance-tuning, finite-element-method, geometry, mesh

I have a MeshRegion `R` and I want to extract all pairs of adjacent faces efficiently. The way that I've been computing this is demonstrated below:

```
R = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]];
faces = MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
adj = Select[Subsets[faces, {2}],Length[Intersection[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] == 2 &];
```

Of course, this is not very efficient since I explicitly construct all pairs of faces and then filter them by requiring that they have both contain two of the same vertices. Any thoughts on how I could compute the same thing efficiently?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Szabolcs' [IGraphM](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=igraphM+github&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) package that's super easy and fast (1000 times faster for your given example):

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
R = DiscretizeRegion[Sphere[]];

pairs = UpperTriangularize[IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 2, 2]]["NonzeroPositions"];
facepairs = Partition[
  MeshCells[R, 2, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]][[Flatten[pairs]]],
  2
  ];
```

For the development history of this code see [How to obtain the cell-adjacency graph of a mesh?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160443) Also notice that the code  the code in my answer [160457](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/160457) there is a bit more up to date and hence a bit faster.

Answer (score 4):

**NDSolve`FEM - "BoundaryConnectivity"**

If you allow connections through a vertex to define neighbors, you can use `` NDSolve`FEM ``:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[R];
connectivity = bmesh["BoundaryConnectivity"];

HighlightMesh[R, {Style[MeshCells[R, {2, 1}], Red], 
  MeshCells[R, #] & /@ Thread[{2, connectivity[[1]]}]}]
```

[image]

We can modify `connectivity` to keep only elements adjacent through an edge:

```
connectivity2 = MapIndexed[Function[{x, ind}, 
  DeleteCases[x, 0|_?(Length[Intersection[faces[[ind[[1]]]], faces[[#]]]] != 2&)]], 
 connectivity];


HighlightMesh[R, {Style[MeshCells[R, {2, 1}], Red], 
  Style[MeshCells[R, {2, 10}], Green], 
  MeshCells[R, {2, #}] & /@ connectivity2[[1]], 
  MeshCells[R, {2, #}] & /@ connectivity2[[10]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Erm. The implementation involving `Nearest` takes _twice_ as long as OP's implementation... I think the reason is that the chosen distance function is no distance function at all, so `Nearest` cannot take any advantage of it.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, erm indeed:) Should have tested before posting.