# Cell-adjacency Graph of a Square Mesh

Tags: matrix, mesh, lattices, graphs-and-networks

Consider the list of points

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}
```

I want to use them to define a 2x2 square mesh using `VoronoiMesh`, where each cell has two neighbours. Following the discussion in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/166491/64001), consider the following code

```
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, ImageSize -> Medium];
conn = mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[2, 1]];
adj = conn.Transpose[conn];
centers = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];
g = AdjacencyGraph[adj, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
   VertexCoordinates -> centers];
Show[mesh, g]
```

[image]

As one can see, unlike other meshes, this one does not seem to work exactly as I want, since the diagonal edge should not appear. Why is this happening? Any way of avoiding that edge and get

[image]

as one would expect from a square lattice?

**Edit:** As noticed in the comment section, some of the polygons seem to have sharing edges that are single points, which is enough for them to be considered neighbouring cells. This effect is unchanged with the size of the lattice. If I consider, for example, the points

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 7}, {j, 5}], 1];
```

I get

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this? Maybe omit the extra edge in a way that doesn't this or other non-square meshes. For example, considering a random `VoronoiMesh`, nothing seems to wrong, though it could, theoretically, go

[image]

Comment: Something somewhat strange... faces 3 and 4 have 5 sides: `In[52]:= MeshCells[mesh, 2]

Out[52]= {Polygon[{4, 1, 3, 6}], Polygon[{5, 1, 2, 9}], 
 Polygon[{7, 3, 1, 1, 5}], Polygon[{8, 2, 1, 1, 4}]}`. But notice `1` is repeated twice...so structurally they share an edge, but that 'edge' is really just a point.

Comment: That's right. Would it be possible to delete that `1` in a reasonably natural manner? So that it wouldn't affect other possible meshes?

Comment: The problem persists with bigger lattices. Please see edit section.

Comment: IGraph/M handles this well. Did you try it? `IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph[mesh, 2]`. You may also want to add `VertexCoordinates -> Automatic`

Comment: No, I haven't tried yet. I think we briefly talked about this in some other post. Does IGraph/M work well with `Manipulate` and `CDFDeploy`? I'm not entirely sure how to deal with `Get` or `Need` in these type of applications. If not, I would avoid it for now, but maybe I could base it on your definition of `IGMeshCellAdjacencyGraph` or the adjacency matrix (which is actually what I'm interested in).

Comment: Delaunay triangulation, for example, works fine in perfectly hexagonal lattices, though it seems to fail in some other cases, including the square one. Previously I was simply using `DelaunayMesh[pts]["AdjacencyMatrix"]`.

Comment: Well, it's open-source so you can check ... It's based on Henrik's answer in the linked question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can delete the rows in our incidence matrix that correspond to these edges of length `0`.

```
pts = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 7}, {j, 5}], 1];

mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, ImageSize -> Medium];
conn = mesh["ConnectivityMatrix"[1, 2]];

lens = PropertyValue[{mesh, 1}, MeshCellMeasure];
$threshold = 0.;
keep = Pick[Range[MeshCellCount[mesh, 1]], UnitStep[Subtract[$threshold, lens]], 0];
conn = conn[[keep]];

adj = Transpose[conn].conn;
centers = PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];
g = AdjacencyGraph[adj, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", VertexCoordinates -> centers];

Show[mesh, g]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
L1 = 2; L2 = 2;
mesh = VoronoiMesh @ Tuples[Range /@ {L1, L2}];
centers = Rationalize @ PropertyValue[{mesh, 2}, MeshCellCentroid];

g1 = VertexReplace[GridGraph[{L2, L1}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
      VertexCoordinates -> centers[[Ordering @ centers]], 
    {v_ :> Ordering[centers][[v]]}];

Show[mesh, g1]
```

[image]

For `L1 = 7; L2 = 5;` the same approach gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the unwanted edges using [`EdgeDelete`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EdgeDelete.html):

```
Show[mesh, EdgeDelete[g, UndirectedEdge[a_, b_] /; 
   (FreeQ[0][Chop[Differences[PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ {a, b}]]])]]
```

[image]

For `g` generated using `pts = Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 7}, {j, 5}], 1];` we get

[image]